# Menu and Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a Menu that has MenuItems displayed with a scrollbar or a ScrollViewer. I have many items to display in the menu and I just want to display a few of them and let the user scroll down for the others. It would look like a ListBox but it is inside a menu. I already tried adding a listbox to a menu. It works; but looks ugly and it is buggy so, I thought I would re-do it with MenuItems. I have not found anything significant on the internet so I thought I would ask. I have done some code already; but it does not work:

```
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Width="80" Header="Test">
                    <MenuItem Header="Test2">
            </MenuItem>

            <Separator></Separator>
            <!--<ScrollViewer>-->
                <MenuItem Header="Test3">
                    <!--<ScrollBar></ScrollBar>-->
                        <MenuItem Header="Test4"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test5"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test6"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test7"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>                        
             <!--</ScrollViewer>-->

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

The scrollviewer and the scrollbar are commented out but on un-commenting them I get an error in the case of the scrollviewer or a scrollbar on top of the menuitems in the case of the scroll bar. any ideas, articles, code, etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried just making a [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) template and just wrapping your `ContentPresenter` in a `ScrollViewer` and that not work? Or is that the part you're missing and I should have added it as an answer?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your comment I say yes, please, add it as an answer.

Comment: I think @denismorozov beat me to it, but as long as you got your remedy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Menu>
        <MenuItem Width="80" Header="Test">
            <MenuItem Header="A"/>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header="B">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="100">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <MenuItem Header="B1"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B2"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B3"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B4"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B5"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B6"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B7"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B8"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B9"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B10"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B11"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B12"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B13"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B14"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B15"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="B16"></MenuItem>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="C">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="100">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <MenuItem Header="C1"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C2"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C3"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C4"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C5"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C6"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C7"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C8"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C9"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C10"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C11"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C12"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C13"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C14"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C15"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="C16"></MenuItem>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="D"/>
            <MenuItem Header="F"/>
            <MenuItem Header="G"/>
            <MenuItem Header="H"/>
            <MenuItem Header="I"/>
            <MenuItem Header="J"/>
            <MenuItem Header="K"/>

        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

OR you could set something up in the style... but then you have to know how many menu items you need.. so I don't really care so much for the style as it (at least this one) isn't for general use. But maybe this will give you other ideas or get you started.

```
<Style x:Key="MenuWithScroll"  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="B">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding title1}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding title2}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding title3}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding title4}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding title5}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You don't need to know how many you need. If you retemplate the menu items, you can put the item host (a StackPanel by default) inside a ScrollViewer and bind the template's max height property to it for an application-wide style.